# js: Object returning human readable string

Tags: javascript, function, tostring

Is it possible to make an object so that returns a human readable string?

```
function hsl_obj(h, s, l) {
    this.h = h;
    this.s = s;
    this.l = l;
    this.__str__ = function() {
        return "hsl(" + this.h + ", " + this.s + "%, " + this.l + ")";
    }
}

var badass = new hsl_obj(76, 64, 59); // #BADA55
console.log(badass); // --> hsl(76, 64%, 59%)
console.log(badass.h); // --> 76
console.log(badass.s); // --> 64
console.log(badass.l); // --> 59

$("p").css("background-color", badass);
$("#ph").html(badass.h);
$("#ps").html(badass.d);
$("#pl").html(badass.l);
```

I know that I could change `__str__` to `toString` and just use `badass.toString()` instead, but I want to know if this method is possible. It would be somewhat like the `__str__` method in python.

**EDIT**

Right now when I call `badass`, it returns `hsl_obj {h: 76, s: 64, l: 59}`.

Comment: Maybe `JSON.stringify(obj);` ?

Comment: Was about to say the same since question is bit strange :)

Comment: When should string be returned?

Comment: agree with mrlew.. use JSON.stringify(obj) this will give you json string of your object

Answer (score 0):

You want PrettyPrint.js

https://github.com/padolsey-archive/prettyprint.js

I have a bookmarklet for it that dumps `window` on any page.

```
javascript:!function(){var t=document.createElement("script");t.setAttribute("src","https://rawgit.com/padolsey-archive/prettyprint.js/master/prettyprint.js"),document.head.appendChild(t),t.onload=function(){var t=prettyPrint(window);document.body.innerHTML="",document.body.insertBefore(t,document.body.firstChild)}}();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your question is kind of confusing, it will work the way you have it provided you call the method `badass.__str__()`if you're not wanting to call the function to get the string value, you can try setting a `getter` for `__string__` like this:

```
function hsl_obj(h,s,l) {
  this.h = h;
  this.s = s;
  this.l = l;
}
Object.defineProperty(hsl_obj.prototype, '__str__', {
  get: function() {
    return "hsl(" + this.h + ", " + this.s + "%, " + this.l + ")";
  }
})

var badass = new hsl_obj(76, 64, 59);
console.log(badass.__str__) // --> "hsl(76, 64%, 59)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking the confusion here is that you are expecting console.log() to always expect a string, but it will accept any type and try to represent it.

So when you pass it an object, it shows you that object.
Maybe using `console.log(badass + '');` will result in what you were expecting?

The question is confusing though, i think it needs to be more specific.
I am just interpreting the question my own way...